# return a text array with a define delimiter

Tags: postgresql

I would like to return an array::text with ',' as delimiter from a function

my data to fill the array came from e.g :

```
select distinct name from table1;
```

do I have to loop through my query to dynamically add each value in the array?

something like:

```
declare 
 f_record;
 str_text text[];
begin
for f in select name from table1 loop
 insert name into str_text;
end loop;
 
 return str_text;
```

or could I just use something like:

```
return array(select distinct name from table1);
```

Comment: Have a look at the array_agg function

Comment: From [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html): `select  array_agg(distinct name) from table1`.

Comment: `return array(select ...)` should work just fine. What happened when you tried?

Comment: If you want to return an array (type `text[]`), there is no delimiter, just the sequence of element values. If you want to return a string (type `text`) where the elements are joined by that comma delimiter, use `string_agg(distinct name, ',')`.

Comment: you're right, it's working in my sql editor with the select array(select ...); might be how i declare my returns, is returns text[] is the right syntax?

Comment: Why build a function that replicates an existing function?